# GUI frameworks for Java

Tags: java, user-interface, frameworks

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions of frameworks to give an old desktop application a much needed facelift.
The application has had a long life without anyone giving any attention to its exterior resulting in a monster with an 80s look.

I've just downloaded and tried [MyDoggy](http://mydoggy.sourceforge.net/) framework for making windows floatable and dockable. So I'm looking similar for quick and easy fixes that will bring a dead looking application back to life.

Comment: Not a framework, but consider getting a copy of "Filthy Rich Clients"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't want to rewrite your app, right? Because it seems as all the other guys think so, suggesting SWT and JavaFX.

To pimp your existing Swing App, take a look at [jgoodies.com](http://www.jgoodies.com/), [the substance look and feel](https://substance.dev.java.net/) or the [swinglabs](http://www.swinglabs.org/index.jsp)

Comment: Exactly, minimum effort. I'm going to try out substance and see how that looks. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

Just changing the look and feel and some components might already help to give your application a second youth. Consider for example Violet which is IMO a nice looking application. It uses a custom [theme](http://violet.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/violet/VioletFramework/src/main/java/com/horstmann/violet/framework/theme/VistaBlueTheme.java?revision=1.1&view=markup) based on the [PgsLookAndFeel](http://pagosoft.com/products/pgslookandfeel/index.html) and some components from [L2FProd.com](http://www.l2fprod.com/common/index.php).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could give Oracle's [ADF](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/adf/index.html) a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with the latest and greatest, you could try [JavaFX](http://www.sun.com/software/javafx/). Bu tof course using good old [swing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/) or the more OS agnostic [SWT](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) does the trick as well.

Comment: My understanding is that JavaFX is for rich Internet applications, not desktop applications as Alex is looking for. However, Swing and SWT are both valid suggestions.

Comment: I think he want to makeover his existing swing app, not rewrite it.

Comment: JavaFX is targeted for destop applications as well. There are already JavaFX desptop applications out there Vuze is one example. And it looks great.

Answer (score 0):

There's ofcourse the [Eclipse Rich Client Platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform) or the [Netbeans Rich Client Platform](http://www.netbeans.org/features/platform/index.html).

Comment: Oops, fixed the links. Thanks.